# Django Basic HTTP Auth "NoneType" object has no attribute "username"

Tags: python, django, authentication, basic-authentication, django-middleware

Here is my middlware:

```
class BasicAuthMiddleware():

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"):
            encoded_auth =  request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")
            encoded_auth = encoded_auth[6:]
            auth = base64.b64decode(encoded_auth)
            auth_email = auth.split(":")[0]
            auth_password = auth.split(":")[1]
            user = authenticate(username=auth_email, password=auth_password)
```

Here is an example of the rpc/api call we make to login:

```
@rpc("user", "signin")
@pre("email", validate_email)
def _(request, user, email, password):

    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

    if not user:
        raise ApiException(400, "The email or password you entered is incorrect.")

    if not user.is_active:
        raise ApiException(403, "This account has been deactivated.")

    login(request, user)

    return user.toDict()
```

Ihave included the middleware in setting.py

I get this error when using postman trying to an api call to this:

```
@rpc("reservation", "listCurrent", loggedIn=True)
def _(request, user):

    return [dict(r.toDict(), **{ 'cancelationPolicy': evaluated_cancelation_policies(user, r.user, r.resource, r.modality, r.timeFrom, r.timeTo, r.count) }) for r in Reservation.objects.filter(user=user, deleted=False, timeTo__gt=timezone.now()).order_by('-timeFrom', '-timeTo')]
```

It seems that user variable is equal to none. Since normally it is part of the request but in the middleware process_request can only take 2 arguments like `self, request`.

I feel like I am not understanding something here. I am pretty new to django so just trying to figure this out. How would I go about using my basic http authentication middleware to authenticate in this case?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback.

Comment: Are you supposed to name all of your rpc methods `_`? I feel like that could come back to haunt at some point...